# Diffie Hellman algorithm on browser

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman, node-crypto

NodeJS have crypto module where DiffieHellman is a class. So, I can use this method to generate key and compute key.

But, client also need to create another instance of diffiehellman class. But how to do that? Can I use crypto module on client side? If yes then how, any solution? Here are my client side code...

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Generate server's keys...
const server = crypto.createDiffieHellman(139);
const serverKey = server.generateKeys();
//send p=prime and g=generator to the client
```

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has own "crypto" module to use [DiffieHellman](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/crypto/diffiehellman.js) algorithm, so you can watch it and write it on browser on your own.

Second way is take library ready for use (on github or else), e.g. [this one](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/diffie-hellman).

Comment: Sir, I want to use the library. i make a script to use this libreary already, but facing a error that **createDiffieHellman** is not a function.(your second option). I tried to read the readme.md but can't understand what i need to do.                      
`<script>const crypto = require('crypto');
const client = crypto.createDiffieHellman(139);
</script>`

Comment: You cant do that on browser, because its a node.js module, not browser module.

Comment: Maybe this should help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify

Comment: No, I tried this crypto-browserify but total failure. Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63500683/7483046

Comment: But, I tried to call createDiffiHellman, as they show in there example but. It arises error. After lot of observation I found they mistake `createDiffiHellman` spelling on `bundle.js`. After make it correct it says `this is not implemented yet`. And, I checked the bundle.js again and observe they only export the `createHash` properties which they shows in their example. And all other properties are not implemented yet.